# Do I need to upgrade Gemfile.lock manually?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gemfile, gemfile.lock

In the [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.67.0&to=0.67.4) from v0.67.0 to v0.67.4, one of the files that it says changes is `Gemfile.lock`. Do I need to make these changes manually, or will running `npm i` etc do these automatically?

Answer (score -1):

delete the pods folder and Gemfile.lock, install the pods it will automatically update those